# Unable to get proper message Id of message in rocketchat

Tags: rocket.chat

When i try to send a new message on pressing enter . I am getting message id as "0" when i try to log the message in message.js file . But only for a few messages i am getting id as "0" but database is not showing any entry with message id as "0" .

```
const {msg} = this;
console.log("tagamsg",msg._id);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

id was being set as 0 due to another event that was being called at the same time .